# windows azure port range forwarding

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, cloud-hosting, portforwarding

I am running a virtual machine on Windows Azure. Unfortunately the service is virtually unusable (ha!) because it is separated from the Internet by a firewall. Port ranges cannot be opened in the firewall, only individual ports, and only a limited number of those. I would be happy to disable the virtual firewall altogether and rely on the Windows firewall, but that also does not appear to be an option.

Has anyone found a workaround for this port range forwarding issue?

Alternatively, any suggestions for where I can host this server? I am looking for a virtual machine host that will permit me to supply my own disk image. It looks like we can download the VHD file from Windows Azure, so I am looking for a host that will permit upload of a VHD or VMDK file.

Thanks for any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Azure will permit you to upload your own VHD, in the beta portal go to virtual machines, images, add an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can [upload your own VHD](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/) to Windows Azure Virtual Machines.

Could you please describe what ports you are attempting to open and on what OS?

Any additional information on the scenario you are attempting to enable would be helpful as well.

Comment: As I was unsure of which OS you were using [Here is how to upload a Linux VHD](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/common-tasks/upload-a-vhd/)

Comment: I'm running Windows Server 2008 as a VM on Windows Azure. I have a need to open ports 40000-41000 for example. Opening 1000 ports one by one is impractical. I am thinking of exporting the VM to a VHD file and hosting it at iLand instead.

Comment: You could create a small console application which uses the Virtual Machine Management API to [Update a Virtual Machine Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157187.aspx). This will enable you to add a larger number of ports.